# Transform JSON message from XML which has 2 namespaces in WSO2 EI

Tags: xml, wso2, freemarker, xml-namespaces, wso2-micro-integrator

I have xml payload and I want to convert it to json message. For that, I used a payload factory mediator with freemarker template.
My XML has 2 namespaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AAA xmlns="http://www.example.com/XMLSchema">
    <BBB>
        <abc>xxxxxxx</abc>
        <msg>9212840000000996</msg>
        <ref>x212840000000078</ref>
    </BBB>
    <CCC xmlns="http://www.example.com/sc1">
        <cf1>
            <edg>N</edg>
            <nic>000265</nic>
            <ccc>I</ccc>
            <nnn>TESTNOTIF5</nnn>
        </cf1>
    </CCC>
</AAA>
```

This is my payload factory mediator which I implemented based on the documents.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json" template-type="freemarker">
        <format><![CDATA[
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"n1": "http://www.example.com/XMLSchema", "n2": "http://www.example.com/sc1"}
      output_format="XML">
        {  
        "aaaaaa": "TestValue1", 
        "bbbb": "$payload.n1:AAA.n2:CCC.n2:cf1.n2.nic", 
        "ccc": "1299"}]]></format>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>
```

But I can't save this implementation from the integration studio. What is the error here?

Comment: Did you get the latest update of the Integrations Studio? I just tried this and it's saving fine.  And in your freemarker template, ```output_format="XML"``` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this option is only available on API Manager 4.0. The Micro Integrator documentation about the PayloadFactory does not mention the freemarker template.

[Latest Micro integrator docs on PayloadFactory](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/payloadFactory-Mediator/#!)

you could try the following

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>
    {  
    "aaaaaa": "TestValue1", 
    "bbbb": "$1", 
    "ccc": "1299"}</format>
    <args>
        <arg expression="//ns1:CCC/ns1:cf1/ns1:nic" evaluator="xml" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/sc1"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Comment: I'm using API Manager 4.0.0. Is there a way to use freemarker here As I have some logic to use when I convert XML message to JSON message?